# Find out if attributes are identical

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have an array of active record objects. All objects have an attribute `result` and the value of result can be either 'failed' or 'passed'.

My goal is to find out if all result attributes are identical. If not then I will have to return mixed but if they are then I return the value of the attributes.

I currently have this code:

```
if tests.map(&:result).uniq.count != 1
   'mixed'
else
   tests.first.result
end
```

But that first line is quite ugly. I'm sure there is a better way to find out if all results are identical or not but I can't think of any.

Comment: Is it ok that `tests = []` returns `'mixed'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the appropriately named `#all?` method:

```
reference = tests.first.result
if tests.all? { |test| test.result == reference }
  reference
else
  'mixed'
end
```

*Edit:* As tokland points out, you'll want to check if `tests` is empty before any of this. Otherwise, `tests.first` will of course be `nil`.

But you could also do the check in the database layer with something like:

```
if Test.select(:result).distinct.count > 1
  'mixed'
else
  Test.first.try(:result)
end
```

Obviously you'll want to scope the query more specifically.

Also note that here, an empty collection returns a `nil` (because if `Test.first` is `nil`, then `.try(:result)` will also be `nil`).

Comment: Note that this fails when `tests = []`

Comment: @tokland Hm, yeah, good point...

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks pretty to me. Note that there is a more efficient way to check equality for all elements in an enumerable: `xs.each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| x == y }`. I'd write:

```
results = tests.map(&:result)
if results.present? && results.each_cons(2).all? { |r1, r2| r1 == r2 }
  results.first
else
  'mixed'
end
```